# internal server error the server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request

Tags: python, flask

I know this isn't exactly python but I just started learning flask as i am done with python. Whenever i try to execute the following line of code i get the 500 error. Can someone please help me. Thank you.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<name>')
def helloWorld():
 return '<h1> Hello {} </h1>'.format(name)
```

When i do this without name in brackets in route i get no error. But with that i do. What is happening here?

I think the answer should be something like this :

```
Hello Angad(if angad is provided in the parameter of link)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `hello` function makes use of `name`, which hasn't been defined anywhere in the function. You must include it in the parameters:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<name>')
def helloWorld(name):
    return '<h1> Hello {} </h1>'.format(name)
```

This way, Flask can pass the name retrieved from the URL to your function, and your function can use it.

Comment: Thank you. It fixed the problem. I am new to this so thanks for helping me out

Comment: You're welcome! Note that you can accept answers to your questions (the tick mark on the left) and/or upvote them (once you have enough reputation) if you feel that they have solved your problem

Comment: Duly Noted. Thanks again